# inner join and count records recursively

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named Topics and DocumentTopics

Topics table has the following structure

di_name | parentTopic

the records in Topics can be either a main or a child topic of a main topic. If a record is a main topic then the value of parentTopic will be null.

DocumentsTopics has the following structure

doc_name | topic_di_name

documentsTopics holds the records of all my documents by name and their topics. I can join both tables using topics->di_name and documentTopics->topic_di_name

```
SELECT t1.topic_di_name, count(t1.topic_di_name) as count 
FROM DocumentsTopics t1 
INNER JOIN Topics t2
ON t1.topic_di_name = t2.di_name
GROUP BY t1.topic_di_name;
```

but what I actually want to is group the topics by main topics only and get a sum count of all the records under the main topic and all its children's topics. These may drill down to more than one level.

here is a schema with sample data
[image]

There are 2 main topics but only one has siblings. The total count I am looking for is for the main topics only but they should include the counts of all the sibling topics within.

I am guessing the only way to do that is to run a recursive function but I am unsure about how to do that with a single SQL query. Is it even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: This can be done in MySQL 8.x. Do you have MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: And as Gordon says, some sample data and the expected result is critical to help you.

Comment: I can get the newest MySQL. I have a new UBUNTU installation so assume MySQL 8.x. I am  working to get some sample data out there.

Comment: @JohnyDGood "There are 2 main topics but only one has siblings." Did you mean only one has *children*?

Comment: @kevin. I guess. This was just to show that a main topic might have children and might not. Also when it comes to documents, any topic can have document wether its is a main topic or a child of a topic.

Comment: I have an idea but it requires mySql 8.0 which I don't have any access to at the moment to try to work it out.  Anybody know of an sqlFiddle-like site that supports 8.0?

Comment: @kevin https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: maybe it's something with security settings at work, but the 8.0 doesn't work at all on that site for me

Comment: @JohnyDGood Is this only two levels deep? Or can sub-categories have sub-categories?

Comment: @kevin I would prefer unlimited subcategories. In fact, I already have a PHP solution for that with a recursive function that calls numerous queries. I wish there was a more elegant pure SQL  solution.

Comment: @JohnyDGood I think it is possible with recursive cte in mySql 8.0, but I don't have any place to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it using a `UNION` in a sub query in case this makes more sense to anyone:

```
SELECT `der`.`parentTopic`,
  SUM(IF(`dt`.`topic_di_name` = `der`.`subTopic`,1,0)) AS `counter`
FROM (
SELECT `parentTopic`,
  `di_name` AS `subTopic`
FROM `topics` 
WHERE `parentTopic` IS NOT NULL

UNION 

SELECT `di_name` AS `parentTopic`,
  `di_name` AS `subTopic`
FROM `topics`
WHERE `parentTopic` IS NULL) AS `der`
JOIN `documentsTopics` AS `dt` ON `dt`.`topic_di_name` = `der`.`subTopic`
GROUP BY `der`.`parentTopic`
;
```

[Here's this answer in sql fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bf689/30)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure if OP cares if it goes more than one level of subcategories, but if so, this doesn't work
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf33be

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use:

```
SELECT t3.parent_key, count(t3.parent_key)
FROM DocumentsTopics t1 
INNER JOIN Topics t2
ON t1.topic_di_name = t2.di_name
LEFT JOIN (select *, coalesce(parentTopic, di_name) parent_key from Topics) t3
ON t2.di_name = t3.di_name
GROUP BY t3.parent_key
```

Comment: Can you show in your Q what the data structure for a second level would look like? And would it have a max of two?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for two levels.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcjUtUfxsn4yaKnQhmQJ6d/5

```
SELECT IFNULL(t.parentTopic,t.di_name) AS main_topics,COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM DocumentsTopics d 
INNER JOIN Topics t ON d.topic_di_name=t.di_name 
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in mySql 8.0 and give you nested results more than one level deep, but I don't have access to test

```
with recursive cte as (
  SELECT `parentTopic`,
  `di_name` 
FROM `topics` 
WHERE `parentTopic` IS NOT NULL
  union all
  select
  `parentTopic`,
  `di_name` 
  from `topics` t2
  inner join cte on t2.`parentTopic` = cte.`di_name`
  )

  select * from cte
```